# How can I use D3DXLoadMeshFromX with Direct3D 11?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to write some class for loading meshes from X files.

But I can't use the function `D3DXLoadMeshFromX` because its third parameter is `LPDirect3DDevice9`.

In my D3D initialization code I don't have variable of this type. Did I initialize D3D incorrectly? How can I call this function?

Comment: `LPDirect3DDevice9` is a typedef for `IDirect3DDevice9*`. Try passing a pointer to your device.

Comment: In my code it is just ID3D11Device*

Comment: My guess is that `ID3D11Device11` implements `ID3D11Device9` so that should work to. Just test it.

Comment: Its definition looks like this:
`ID3D11Device : public IUnknown`
So i dont understand...

I tried this:
 `..., (LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9)m_pd3dDevice, ..`
But i dont think it will work. I cant test right now..

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff The D3D9 and 11 device interfaces are not related at all; D3DXLoadMeshFromX doesn't work with 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3DXLoadMeshFromX is not supported in DirectX 11.

You will have to create your own model importer for a file format. Something simple like .obj would be a good place to start.

Comment: Is there any open-source for loading OBJ mesh?

Comment: This is a very basic tutorial for loading .obj files http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut08.html

Answer (score 1):

`LPDirect3DDevice9` is an alias for the type `IDirect3DDevice9 *`, which is a pointer to a [Direct3D 9 device object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You are using D3D11, which means you have a completely incompatible device interface. Your device initialization is (probably) fine, you will just not be able to use `D3DXLoadMeshFromX` because it's only supported on an older version of Direct3D.

D3DX was [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) after D3D10. The functionality you are looking for is no longer available as part of the core SDK, you will need to find it elsewhere.

You can either write your own, for any number of file formats including `.X` (`.obj` is popular and [Google can help you find tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=direct3d%2011%20load%20mesh)) or utilize a 3rd party library such as [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Also see for a smattering of functionality from D3DX: http://directxtk.codeplex.com/